# What angle would frame dragging shove matter in the innermost accretion disk relative to the equatorial plane or orbit?

Tags: black-holes, frame-dragging, accretion-disk

I understand that frame dragging will imbue momentum on plasma orbiting a black hole at close range.

My first question is - is this kinetic energy inserted very narrowly relative to the equatorial region of orbit? *How do I say this correctly...* An accretion disk would be a relatively flat pancake. However as the material friction brakes itself closer and closer to the event horizon, the rotational energy of the black hole should logically uhm "shear" the matter perpendicular in a much wider angle relative to the accretion disk, much like the wake of a ship plowing up water. As a result of frame dragging.

I'd even go as far as speculate there should be a "dike" of matter shoved outward by (*) the radiation of hyperheated matter near the event horizon and (*) matter being rammed aside by the frame dragging. My question is, how far "up" from the orbital plane would matter get "sprayed" up?

In smaller stellar mass black holes the actual hole relative to the accretion disk should be minute - a black hole is ten+ kilometers - an active accretion disk around that *speck* should be tens of thousands of kilometers thick, and "meaningfully" extend an AU, uhm... *arguably*.

If the shear inflicted on the innermost region of the disk is not smooth, it could have a kitchen blender effect, especially in conjunction with the radiation washing material up and down from a flat orbit.

If my speculation is true, whow far up and down from the orbital plane would such a *traffic jam* extend? Could the effect cause the black hole to be significantly obscured as the traffic jam of material pushed *outwards and upwards* envelops the event horizon?

It's so difficult to find suitable words to describe this....